# ServiceStack translateTo sending back null object

Tags: servicestack

I have the following Response Class:

```
 
public class PatientFindResponse : IHasResponseStatus
    {
        public class Patient
        {

            public int PeopleId { get; set; }


            public string FirstName { get; set; }


            public string LastName { get; set; }


        }


        public Patient Result { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my Service:

```
public class PatientFindService : IService
    {
        public ISessionFactory NHSessionFactory { get; set; }

        public PatientFindService(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            NHSessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public object Execute(PatientFind request)
        {
            using (var session = NHSessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {

                var result = session.Load<MyCompany.MyProduct.Entities.People>(request.PeopleId);

                return new PatientFindResponse
                {
                    Result = result.TranslateTo<PatientFindResponse.Patient>()
                };

            }
        }
    }
```

The var result has data from loading the Model, but the translateTo creates and object where the values are all null, the properties are the same name as what is in my model although I don't include all properties in my DTO that are in my model, not sure if that is why the translateTo doesn't work or not, I get no errors.

Here is my Model:

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.Entities
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class People
    {
        public People()
        {
            ShrEpisodes = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet();     
        }
        public virtual string AdvDirectives
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? AdvDirectivesDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? AllergyUpdatedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string AlternatePatientId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? ArchiveDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string ArchivedInfo
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string AuthorizationSignature
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string BloodType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string BreakGlass
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string Comment
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual short CompanyId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? Dor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string ExternalPatientId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? FamilyHistUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? GuarantorId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? HealthCareMaintenanceUpdatedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string IncludeInClergyList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string IncludeInDirectory
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? LastInpatientAdmittedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? LastInpatientDischargedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? LastOutpatientAdmittedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? LastTetanusDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string LivingWill
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? LivingWillDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? MedicalHistUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? MedicalRecordNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? MedicationUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int ModifiedBy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime ModifiedOn
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? MothersPeopleId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int PeopleId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? NkaEnteredBy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? NkaEnteredOn
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? NoInformation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoKnownAllergies
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoKnownMedication
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoKnownMedicationInformationSource
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? NoKnownMedicationUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoKnownProblem
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoKnownProblemInformationSource
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? NoKnownProblemUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string NoMedicationHistoryAssessed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? ObstetricalHistoryUpdatedDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? OnGoingProbUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string OrganDonor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? OrgonDonorDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string OtherPatientId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? PatientId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string PatientPreference
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string PatientRefusedSigning
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string PersonName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? PrimaryPharmacyId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? PrimaryPhysicianId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? PrivacyNoticeDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual int? RcopiaId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? RcopiaLastUpdateDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string Relationship
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? SpouseDor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string Status
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual short? StorageLocationId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string UnableToReportMedication
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual string UnableToReportMedicationInformationSource
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual DateTime? UnableToReportMedicationUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual GlbPerson GlbPerson
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet ShrEpisodes
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
                return true;

            return Equals(obj as People);
        }

        public virtual bool Equals(People obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;

            if (Equals(AdvDirectives, obj.AdvDirectives) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(AdvDirectivesDate, obj.AdvDirectivesDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(AllergyUpdatedDate, obj.AllergyUpdatedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(AlternatePatientId, obj.AlternatePatientId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ArchiveDate, obj.ArchiveDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ArchivedInfo, obj.ArchivedInfo) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(AuthorizationSignature, obj.AuthorizationSignature) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(BloodType, obj.BloodType) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(BreakGlass, obj.BreakGlass) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(Comment, obj.Comment) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(CompanyId, obj.CompanyId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(Dor, obj.Dor) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ExternalPatientId, obj.ExternalPatientId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(FamilyHistUpdated, obj.FamilyHistUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(FirstName, obj.FirstName) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(GuarantorId, obj.GuarantorId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(HealthCareMaintenanceUpdatedDate, obj.HealthCareMaintenanceUpdatedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(IncludeInClergyList, obj.IncludeInClergyList) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(IncludeInDirectory, obj.IncludeInDirectory) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LastInpatientAdmittedDate, obj.LastInpatientAdmittedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LastInpatientDischargedDate, obj.LastInpatientDischargedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LastName, obj.LastName) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LastOutpatientAdmittedDate, obj.LastOutpatientAdmittedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LastTetanusDate, obj.LastTetanusDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LivingWill, obj.LivingWill) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(LivingWillDate, obj.LivingWillDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(MedicalHistUpdated, obj.MedicalHistUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(MedicalRecordNumber, obj.MedicalRecordNumber) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(MedicationUpdated, obj.MedicationUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ModifiedBy, obj.ModifiedBy) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ModifiedOn, obj.ModifiedOn) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(MothersPeopleId, obj.MothersPeopleId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PeopleId, obj. PeopleId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NkaEnteredBy, obj.NkaEnteredBy) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NkaEnteredOn, obj.NkaEnteredOn) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoInformation, obj.NoInformation) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownAllergies, obj.NoKnownAllergies) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownMedication, obj.NoKnownMedication) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownMedicationInformationSource, obj.NoKnownMedicationInformationSource) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownMedicationUpdated, obj.NoKnownMedicationUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownProblem, obj.NoKnownProblem) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownProblemInformationSource, obj.NoKnownProblemInformationSource) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoKnownProblemUpdated, obj.NoKnownProblemUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(NoMedicationHistoryAssessed, obj.NoMedicationHistoryAssessed) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(ObstetricalHistoryUpdatedDate, obj.ObstetricalHistoryUpdatedDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(OnGoingProbUpdated, obj.OnGoingProbUpdated) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(OrganDonor, obj.OrganDonor) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(OrgonDonorDate, obj.OrgonDonorDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(OtherPatientId, obj.OtherPatientId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PatientId, obj.PatientId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PatientPreference, obj.PatientPreference) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PatientRefusedSigning, obj.PatientRefusedSigning) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PersonName, obj.PersonName) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PrimaryPharmacyId, obj.PrimaryPharmacyId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PrimaryPhysicianId, obj.PrimaryPhysicianId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(PrivacyNoticeDate, obj.PrivacyNoticeDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(RcopiaId, obj.RcopiaId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(RcopiaLastUpdateDate, obj.RcopiaLastUpdateDate) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(Relationship, obj.Relationship) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(SpouseDor, obj.SpouseDor) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(Status, obj.Status) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(StorageLocationId, obj.StorageLocationId) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(UnableToReportMedication, obj.UnableToReportMedication) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(UnableToReportMedicationInformationSource, obj.UnableToReportMedicationInformationSource) == false) return false;
            if (Equals(UnableToReportMedicationUpdated, obj.UnableToReportMedicationUpdated) == false) return false;
            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int result = 1;

            result = (result * 397) ^ (AdvDirectives != null ? AdvDirectives.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (AdvDirectivesDate != null ? AdvDirectivesDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (AllergyUpdatedDate != null ? AllergyUpdatedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (AlternatePatientId != null ? AlternatePatientId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (ArchiveDate != null ? ArchiveDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (ArchivedInfo != null ? ArchivedInfo.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (AuthorizationSignature != null ? AuthorizationSignature.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (BloodType != null ? BloodType.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (BreakGlass != null ? BreakGlass.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Comment != null ? Comment.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ CompanyId.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Dor != null ? Dor.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (ExternalPatientId != null ? ExternalPatientId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (FamilyHistUpdated != null ? FamilyHistUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (FirstName != null ? FirstName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (GuarantorId != null ? GuarantorId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (HealthCareMaintenanceUpdatedDate != null ? HealthCareMaintenanceUpdatedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (IncludeInClergyList != null ? IncludeInClergyList.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (IncludeInDirectory != null ? IncludeInDirectory.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LastInpatientAdmittedDate != null ? LastInpatientAdmittedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LastInpatientDischargedDate != null ? LastInpatientDischargedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LastName != null ? LastName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LastOutpatientAdmittedDate != null ? LastOutpatientAdmittedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LastTetanusDate != null ? LastTetanusDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LivingWill != null ? LivingWill.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (LivingWillDate != null ? LivingWillDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (MedicalHistUpdated != null ? MedicalHistUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (MedicalRecordNumber != null ? MedicalRecordNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (MedicationUpdated != null ? MedicationUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ ModifiedBy.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ ModifiedOn.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ (MothersPeopleId != null ? MothersPeopleId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ PeopleId.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NkaEnteredBy != null ? NkaEnteredBy.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NkaEnteredOn != null ? NkaEnteredOn.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoInformation != null ? NoInformation.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownAllergies != null ? NoKnownAllergies.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownMedication != null ? NoKnownMedication.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownMedicationInformationSource != null ? NoKnownMedicationInformationSource.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownMedicationUpdated != null ? NoKnownMedicationUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownProblem != null ? NoKnownProblem.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownProblemInformationSource != null ? NoKnownProblemInformationSource.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoKnownProblemUpdated != null ? NoKnownProblemUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (NoMedicationHistoryAssessed != null ? NoMedicationHistoryAssessed.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (ObstetricalHistoryUpdatedDate != null ? ObstetricalHistoryUpdatedDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (OnGoingProbUpdated != null ? OnGoingProbUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (OrganDonor != null ? OrganDonor.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (OrgonDonorDate != null ? OrgonDonorDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (OtherPatientId != null ? OtherPatientId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PatientId != null ? PatientId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PatientPreference != null ? PatientPreference.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PatientRefusedSigning != null ? PatientRefusedSigning.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PersonName != null ? PersonName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PrimaryPharmacyId != null ? PrimaryPharmacyId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PrimaryPhysicianId != null ? PrimaryPhysicianId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PrivacyNoticeDate != null ? PrivacyNoticeDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (RcopiaId != null ? RcopiaId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (RcopiaLastUpdateDate != null ? RcopiaLastUpdateDate.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Relationship != null ? Relationship.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (SpouseDor != null ? SpouseDor.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Status != null ? Status.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (StorageLocationId != null ? StorageLocationId.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (UnableToReportMedication != null ? UnableToReportMedication.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (UnableToReportMedicationInformationSource != null ? UnableToReportMedicationInformationSource.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (UnableToReportMedicationUpdated != null ? UnableToReportMedicationUpdated.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important info to show here are the definitions of the 2 types you're trying to translate. Make sure both have **public properties** with the same name.

Also the best way to diagnose problems is to isolate them, e.g. you don't need ServiceStack or NHibernate to test the `TranslateTo<T>` functionality, it's much easier to see what's going on if you test the result in isolation, e.g:

```
var model = new MyCompany.MyProduct.Entities.People { ... };
var dto = model.TranslateTo<PatientFindResponse.Patient>();
dto.PrintDump(); //Print the output of the translated object
```

Another issue with your sample is that your service implements [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) `IService` but you're using the Old API's **Execute()** method instead of **Any()**, e.g. your service should look something like:

```
public class PatientFindService : IService 
{
    public object Any(PatientFind request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using ServiceStack.Interfaces Version 3.7.8.0 when I go to IService, I don't see any Any method only Execute, do I have the wrong version?

Comment: 3.7x is extremely old consider upgrading, the latest version is 3.9.33

Comment: Ok I updated to 3.9.33, I still don't see an Any method definition in the object browser for the interface IService. Ahh ok must be just handling that under the covers somewhere.

Comment: I have verified that Properties are public and same name too.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the class definitions of both types?

Comment: I will try I, did change the example I posted for privacy reasons. In other words my model is not really called People and the Id is really called something else but the property names do match in both class definitions. I created my model with Visual NHibernate and fluent mappings. I will add it to my question than just remove it later.

Comment: Ok I added it and had to change my example a bit.

Comment: I've added this in this [standalone test which passes](https://gist.github.com/4612922#file-mappingtest-cs-L5). You have something else wrong with this code, that's not related to mapping.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23258/discussion-between-outoftouch-and-mythz)

Comment: I tried the same test as you in my service and it translates fine, when I try to translate the NHibernate created Enitity it fails.

Comment: The code to do the translation is the same so it has to be something with the nHibernate object that the translate doesn't like. To be honest it makes no sense to me the code is the same.

Comment: I do notice one difference when creating the Entity new by hand it's value and type are MyCompany.MyProduct.Entities.People, but when created from NHibernate the value is the same but the type says MyCompany.MyProduct.Entities.People{PeopleProxy}. I wonder if that makes any difference.

Comment: My NHibernate session factory is registerd with the funq ioc container, in global.asax

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is as I don't use NHibernate, but I suspect there is something odd/different with NHibernate's proxy class.

Comment: Is TranslateTo your own custom rolled mapping?

Comment: @Mythz- I appreciate all your help, I was wondering if you could try a simple test with NHibernate to see why the NHibernate proxy is causing the SS TranslateTo to fail. I tried AutoMapper and it was able to deal with the NHibernate proxy to DTO mapping, from what I read though it seems that was not always the case eithier with that tool and it might have been added recently. I would prefer to not have to use a separate mapping tool though if possible and just use SS to do it. Is this feature that could be added to SS or is that out of the question?

Comment: If not I can live I guess with using another mapping tool. Again thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a lot of free time to investigate 3rd party integration issues atm, but if you can prepare a small sample NHibernate project (preferably standalone/e.g. in-memory DB) that I can simply download and run to reproduce the issue, I can take a look at the error.

Comment: I have the sample done that you need, I am trying to get it up on github but I am new to github so having issues with that.

Comment: Is there another way for me to get you these files?

Comment: @OutOFTouch yeah you can attach a zip file to a post on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/servicestack)

Comment: Ok I finally got it pushed to github [here](https://github.com/OutOfTouch/SSNHibernateBug)

Comment: ok, it's fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/c42eb0dc720c74c92b869f7bc96349d74d672c7c) and available in next release (v3.3.34) due tomorrow.

Comment: no probs, FYI This fix was in the latest release pushed to NuGet last night.